# Context of "this" inside private method

Tags: javascript

While working with private methods in JavaScript, I encountered a wired problem. Inside the private method "this" reference was returning handle to Window object instead of the function where it's contained in.

Here's the code, which I'm referring to

```
function MyComponent(elem) {
  alert(this.constructor.name) //returns reference to MyComponent
  function privateMethod() {
    alert(this.constructor.name) 
    //returning Window Object, instead of privateMethod function reference
  }
  privateMethod()
}

new MyComponent(document.createElement('span'))
```

I managed to solve the bug by introducing a reference to "self" from the MyComponent function.

```
function MyComponent(elem) {
  var self = this;
  alert(this.constructor.name) //returns reference to MyComponent
  function privateMethod() {
    alert(self.constructor.name) 
    //after passing the "self" reference its working
  }
  privateMethod()
}

new MyComponent(document.createElement('span'))
```

But one thing which still baffles me is how "this" reference in private method is returning handle to Window Object.

Comment: You may take a look at "this" : http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference of `this` actually depends on the type of function invocation.
You have invoked `privateMethod()` using the *function form* or *simple call* and hence `this` in `privateMethod()` will refer to the global object.Instead if you had used the *constructor form* to invoke `privateMethod()` (i.e `new privateMethod()`) `this` will be referring to the function which it was contained in.

Checkout the simple call topic in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

So

```
function MyComponent(elem) {
  alert(this.constructor.name) //returns reference to MyComponent
      function privateMethod() {
        alert(this.constructor.name)  //returns privateMethod function reference
    }
new privateMethod()
}

new MyComponent(document.createElement('span'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should pass `this` to the function you are calling, such as `privateMethod.call(this);`:

```js
function MyComponent(elem) {
  alert(this.constructor.name) //returns reference to MyComponent
  function privateMethod() {
    alert(this.constructor.name) 
    //returning Window Object, instead of privateMethod function reference
  }
  privateMethod.call(this);
}

new MyComponent(document.createElement('span'))
```